# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE not working for Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm developing an app that needs to take a picture and save it, and show it in the app. It works for Android 4.0 but not for Android 4.2.2 (and I guess for later versions neither).

Here is the code:

```
Button photoBtn = (Button) inflated.findViewById(R.id.btn_photo);
photoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         String fileStorageFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MobiAgenda";
         File file = new File(fileStorageFolder + File.separator + "Contact" + id + ".jpg");
         Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
         imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
    }
});

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {             

        float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap thumb = getThumbnailBitmap(imgPath, Math.round(100*scale));

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imgPath);
            thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }

        takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumb);
        takenPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }  
}
```

Well, as I said before, this code is working on my HTC Desire C. But I have tried it in two different phones running Android 4.2.2 and these are the behaviours I got:

-Droxio B51: The intent opens the camera. Pressing cancel button, the onActivityResult is called back, with result_code = 0 (and the app does nothing --> OK). But when pressing accept button in camera interface, the photo is saved in the phone (different path than given through EXTRA_OUTPUT), but it does not call back onActivityResult.

-Sony Xperia L: The intent opens the camera. After taking the picture, there is no option to cancel or accept (so I guess is accepting it), but it calls onActivityResult with result_code = 0, so the app does nothing. In this case, the picture is not saved in any path of the phone (or at least I coudn't find it).

Why I'm having this two different behaviours? And the most important thing, how can I solve them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I'm having this two different behaviours?

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is invoking a third-party application to take a picture. There are thousands of camera apps, both pre-installed ones and ones that users install from places like the Play Store. None have to necessarily support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and those that do can have bugs, as you are experiencing.

> how can I solve them?

Stop using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, and take pictures yourself in your own app. You have no means of forcing developers to write camera apps that handle `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` properly, and you have no means of forcing users to use camera apps that handle `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` properly.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is using the Android API though Camera class for controlling Preview, Shutter, and all that features?

Comment: @trumpetero: Yes, unfortunately. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is very "casual" and is not well-suited for apps that need consistent and reliable behavior.

Comment: @trumpetero: If you don't find anything better, you may look here: https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam to get you started. I make no guaranties, but at least you'll see what you're up against. I personally thought that the 'ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE' is safer. I was running into all kinds of problems on different devices (stretched preview, images, ...), especially on no-name Chinese phones/tablets. Also, there is a new API, Camera2, but only on Lollipop, I believe.